# Cannot install obspy correctly

Tags: python, installation, anaconda

It could be that obspy is installed, but I've missed a step off the installation process somewhere or some other issue. But in any case I followed the instructions as per this [link](https://github.com/obspy/obspy/wiki/Installation-on-Mac-OS-X-using-Macports) and since I already have installed anacondas, I used:

```
sudo port install py27-obspy

sudo port select python python27
```

then when finished...

```
pip install obspy
```

Then, when running a basic python script in order to test the obspy library I receive import errors:

```
ImportError: No module named obspy.imaging.mopad_wrapper
```

I tried importing the library in my python shell which gave this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/obspy/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from obspy.core.utcdatetime import UTCDateTime  # NOQA
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/obspy/core/__init__.py", line 119, in <module>
    from obspy.core.utcdatetime import UTCDateTime
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/obspy/core/utcdatetime.py", line 20, in <module>
    from obspy.core.util.decorator import deprecated
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/obspy/core/util/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from obspy.core.util.testing import add_doctests, add_unittests
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/obspy/core/util/testing.py", line 28, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so, 2): Library not loaded: libxml2.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: etree.so requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0
```

Has anyone tried installing the obspy library and if so, did you encounter any issues getting this to work?

Comment: Why is this tagged `anaconda`?

Comment: I believed it came as part of the anaconda package or is dependent on.

Comment: But you're not using any conda commands or even the Anaconda Python here. You're using the Python from MacPorts (which is fine), its just not related to Anaconda...

Comment: Ok I see. In any case I can't get the library to run.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using anaconda, you will need to install `obspy` using `conda install`

`conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/obspy obspy`

---

**TL;DR**

Since it is not in their default repository, you need to use the search function to find it:

`anaconda search -t conda obspy`

to find all of the related packages. For `obspy` the search returns:

```
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Run 'anaconda show <USER/PACKAGE>' to get more details:
Packages:
     Name                      |  Version | Package Types   | Platforms
     ------------------------- |   ------ | --------------- | ---------------
     auto/obspydmt             |    0.4.0 | conda           | linux-64
                                          : https://github.com/kasra-hosseini/obspyDMT
     conda-forge/obspy         |    1.0.2 | conda           | linux-64, win-32, win-64, osx-64
     krisvanneste/obspy        |    0.9.2 | conda           | win-64
     mbyt/obspy                |   0.10.0 | conda           | linux-64
     obspy/obspy               |    1.0.2 | conda, pypi     | linux-64, win-32, win-64, linux-32, osx-64
                                          : ObsPy: A Python Toolbox for seismology/seismological observatories.
Found 5 packages
```

Then, it instructs you to use `anaconda show obspy/obspy` for more info about the package, which also gives the install instructions.

```
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Name:    obspy
Summary: ObsPy: A Python Toolbox for seismology/seismological observatories.
Access:  public
Package Types:  conda, pypi
Versions:
   + 0.10.0rc1
   + 0.10.0
   + 0.0.0+archive
   + 0.10.1rc1
   + 0.10.1rc2
   + 0.10.1
   + 0.10.2
   + 1.0.0
   + 1.0.1
   + 1.0.2

To install this package with conda run:
     conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/obspy obspy
To install this package with pypi run:
     pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/obspy/simple obspy
```